# Programmatic Simulink Model Manipulations Reset

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm running a model where I load the model with a function and programmatically select numerous configurable subsystems and turn on signal logging for multiple signals (I invisibly load the system using load_system).

I discovered my signals were not being logged and did a couple checks and realized that my set_param/get_param calls were all executing correctly but that opening the system revealed that the signal logging was not actually turned on.

As an example:
- I call function 1 which loads the model and turns on the signal logging
- I set a debugging point in function 1 prior to simulating the model using the "sim" command
- If I use find_system command I can see a whole list of logged signal handles (while the breakpoint is active)
- If I open the system (open_system), however, the referenced signals are not highlighted as being logged (standard symbol is missing).
- If I rerun find_system - I see that no signals are being logged
- Advancing the breakpoint and running the simulation then results in no data being logged.

I suspect that the model is getting loaded in a weird way, but I'm at a loss as to how I might go about debugging this problem.

Any suggestions welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution to this problem that may be helpful to others.

I was using configurable subsystems and using set_param to force the block choice in my simulink model. However, in many cases, if the default block choice was the desired configuration, I was skipping this step.

I discovered that if I force set_param to run on the block choice, regardless of the default block configuration, I was able to activate signal logging and have the model perform as expected.

An interesting quark in this was that handles for configurable subsystems change. Specifically, loading the system would generate one set of handles. When I then proceeded to open the model, the handles for those same objects were different. Applying the set_param option seems to work around this such that when I turn on logging, the object handles are consistent.

Of course, implicit in this, is that the model must be fully configured before turning on said logging.